# checking javascript is enabled

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am building a html page.  I was to make a quick 1 line test which, if the user has javascript enabled says "javascript on" otherwise says "javascript off" just to let them know.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div id="js_onoff">JavaScript off :(</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("js_onoff").innerHTML = "JavaScript on, yeah! :)";
</script>
```

Comment: I used this, tested and works in firefox at least.  confirmed and thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('JavaScript On');</script>
<noscript>JavaScript Off</noscript>
```

Maybe?

*There are going to be **a lot** of options here.*

Comment: `noscript` elements are ignored by browsers with JavaScript enabled, but blocked (e.g., using an extension like NoScript).

Comment: @Marcel: Actually, it appears the (much) earlier releases didn't but they're [pretty consistently](http://noscript.net/changelog) making that part of their debug efforts (since earlier versions of 2.0.x).

Comment: Looks nice, but there are more alternatives to block JavaScript. I fear we can never rely on those elements, how much I'd like them to behave in a consistent, cross-browser manner.

Comment: I concur, but it'll never happen. And with all the standards there are for the way CSS/Javascript work and render, I wish they'd all agree on default values/behaviors while they're at it.